# How to write tests for Entity Framework Sql providers and access the generated Sql command

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I have a dynamic-LINQ library that generates query expression for any`IQueryable` support lists and EntityFramework...
I want to have some tests to check the entity-framework SQL providers generated SQL queries. The main problem is I can not use the `In-Memory` provider because it doesn't show me the SQL outputs. how can I write these tests without having an actual database installed?
Is there any package that I can use? (I need to test EF SqlServer and MySql providers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [Interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) and suppress the actual execution, following this example from the docs:

```
public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(
    DbCommand command,
    CommandEventData eventData,
    InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (command.CommandText.StartsWith("-- Get_Daily_Message", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_message != null
                && DateTime.UtcNow < _queriedAt + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10))
            {
                command.CommandText = "-- Get_Daily_Message: Skipping DB call; using cache.";
                result = InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>.SuppressWithResult(new CachedDailyMessageDataReader(_id, _message));
            }
        }
    }

    return new ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>>(result);
}
```

[Interceptors - Before Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#before-execution)

Comment: thank you just a small question, do I need to generate the migration to use this feature or it works without having migrations?

Comment: Migrations are completely optional.  Lots of people never use them, and this feature is  unrelated to Migrations.

Comment: This answer is really close to what I need but didn't answer the unit testing part.  for example, probably I should suppress the DB Connection too using `DbConnectionInterceptor` also how to access the provider-generated commands from unit tests. etc... 
anyway, thank you David at least now I know where to look and research.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @David Browne - I ended up with the below code. just want to share it if anyone had a similar problem in the future.

[unit test project link](https://github.com/alirezanet/Gridify/tree/master/test/EntityFrameworkSqlProviderIntegrationTests)

```cs
// interceptors.cs
 public class SuppressConnectionInterceptor : DbConnectionInterceptor
   {
      public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult> ConnectionOpeningAsync(DbConnection connection, ConnectionEventData eventData,
         InterceptionResult result,
         CancellationToken cancellationToken = new())
      {
         result = InterceptionResult.Suppress();
         return base.ConnectionOpeningAsync(connection, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
      }

      public override InterceptionResult ConnectionOpening(DbConnection connection, ConnectionEventData eventData, InterceptionResult result)
      {
         result = InterceptionResult.Suppress();
         return base.ConnectionOpening(connection, eventData, result);
      }
   }

 public class SuppressCommandResultInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
   {
      public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(
         DbCommand command,
         CommandEventData eventData,
         InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
      {
         result = InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>.SuppressWithResult(new EmptyMessageDataReader());

         return result;
      }

      public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(
         DbCommand command,
         CommandEventData eventData,
         InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result,
         CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
      {
         result = InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>.SuppressWithResult(new EmptyMessageDataReader());

         return new ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>>(result);
      }

   public class EmptyMessageDataReader : DbDataReader
   {
   
      private readonly List<User> _users = new List<User>();

      public EmptyMessageDataReader()
      {
      }

      public override int FieldCount
         => 0;

      public override int RecordsAffected
         => 0;

      public override bool HasRows
         => false;

      public override bool IsClosed
         => true;

      public override int Depth
         => 0;

      public override bool Read()
         => false;

      public override int GetInt32(int ordinal)
         => 0;

      public override bool IsDBNull(int ordinal)
         => false;

      public override string GetString(int ordinal)
         => "suppressed message";

      public override bool GetBoolean(int ordinal)
         => true;

      public override byte GetByte(int ordinal)
         => 0;

      public override long GetBytes(int ordinal, long dataOffset, byte[] buffer, int bufferOffset, int length)
         => 0;

      public override char GetChar(int ordinal)
         => '\0';

      public override long GetChars(int ordinal, long dataOffset, char[] buffer, int bufferOffset, int length)
         => 0;

      public override string GetDataTypeName(int ordinal)
         => string.Empty;

      public override DateTime GetDateTime(int ordinal)
         => DateTime.Now;

      public override decimal GetDecimal(int ordinal)
         => 0;

      public override double GetDouble(int ordinal)
         => 0;

      public override Type GetFieldType(int ordinal)
         => typeof(User);

      public override float GetFloat(int ordinal)
         => 0;

      public override Guid GetGuid(int ordinal)
         => Guid.Empty;

      public override short GetInt16(int ordinal)
         => 0;

      public override long GetInt64(int ordinal)
         => 0;

      public override string GetName(int ordinal)
         => "";

      public override int GetOrdinal(string name)
         => 0;

      public override object GetValue(int ordinal)
         => new object();

      public override int GetValues(object[] values)
         => 0;

      public override object this[int ordinal]
         => new object();

      public override object this[string name]
         => new object();

      public override bool NextResult()
         => false;

      public override IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
         => _users.GetEnumerator();
   }

  
   }
```

```cs
// DbContext configuration
   public class MyDbContext : DbContext
   {
      public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

      protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
      {
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;");
         optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new SuppressCommandResultInterceptor());
         optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new SuppressConnectionInterceptor());
         base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
      }
   }
```

```cs
// access queryString in unit test
var actual = _dbContext.Users.Where(q => q.Name == "John").ToQueryString();
```